# Scalar spherical harmonics in $S_n$

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, spherical-harmonics, kaluza-klein

In the Kaluza klein reduction we can "decompose" the spacetime $M_n$ as $M_n = M_4 \otimes K_d$, in which $K_d$ is a compact spacetime. So, functions like a scalar $\phi(x,y)$ can be decomposed as follows (assuming $K_d$ is a sphere)

$$\phi(x,y) = \sum_n \phi_n(x) Y^{I_n}(y),$$

(just like we can decompose functions in quantum mechanics using spherical harmonics $Y_{lm}$). What I am seeking is help in understanding what scalar harmonic functions exactly are!

I mean, I am okay with the fact that $Y$ is an eigenvector of the spherical Laplacian in $d$ dimensions, and I am okay with the decomposition above as well. But I don't know how to "play" with the scalar spherical harmonics $Y$! What I mean is, for example, to show that

$$Y^A D_{\mu} Y_A =  0$$

which apparently is a trivial equality, but I don't know how to prove it! I know we can expand the spherical harmonics (scalar here) as $$Y^I = C^I_{i_1 ... i_k} x^{i_1} ... x^{i_k}$$ with $C$ having some special properties... Even so, it is not clear to me what it means! For example, I couldn't give a simple example of scalar spherical harmonics using the properties I gave above.

Anyway, if you could help me to understand these objects, and also provide a source to study it (detailed), I would be grateful.

Comment: That equality doesn’t look familiar. Does it hold for the usual $Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$ in 3D?

Comment: @Ghoster That's some of the points. I really want to understand these scalar spherical harmonics better, so that i can check it for the known cases, for example.

Comment: Try multiplying the first few $Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$ by $r^l$ and expressing them in terms of $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Comment: Are these the same as "hyperspherical harmonics"?  If so, see, for example, https://www.osti.gov/biblio/7083300, or the book by John Avery: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hyperspherical_Harmonics/6C_sCAAAQBAJ?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The Laplacian in $\mathit L^2 \left(\mathbb R^n\right)$ can easily be decomposed in nested n-spherical coordinates

$$X = r  \ \left(cos \theta_1 , \sin \theta_1 \ \left(\cos \theta_2, \sin \theta_2 \left(\cos  \dots  \sin \theta_{n-2} \ \left( \cos \theta_{n-1}, \sin \theta_{n-1} \right)\right)\right) \right) $$

by expanding all products and flattening the resulting tree.

By the euclidean square of differential of X one deduces the metric as the line element

$$ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 \left( d\theta_1^2+ \sin^2\theta_1 \left( d\theta_2^2 + \dots \sin^2 \theta_{n-2} d\ \theta_{n-1}^2\right)  \right)$$ .

The domains are

$$\theta_k \in \left(0,\pi \right),\ \theta_{n-2} \in \left(0,2\pi\right) $$
because the last angle makes a full round on the maximum circle, all other $\theta_k=\frac{\pi}{2}$ variing between poles at $\left(0,\pi\right)$.

It follows that the scale factors of all differential squares are products of the $\sin \theta_i$ of the smaller indices $i<k$ and  a factor $r$ for each to make it a length.

The volume element therfore has the form

$$dV = dr \wedge r \ d\theta_1 \wedge \dots \wedge r \ \left(\prod_{k<n-1} \sin \theta_k\right) \ d\theta_{n-1}  $$

Now by the usual formula of the Laplacian as the dual of the square of the gradient

$$\int_V dV \ \nabla f \cdot \nabla g =\int_V d^n x \ \rho(x)  \nabla f \cdot \nabla g  = - \int _V  \ d^n x \ \rho(x) \ f(x)   \frac{1}{\rho(x)}\ \nabla^T \cdot \left( \rho(x) \nabla g(x) \right)$$

By the fact, that the component of the gradient in a diagonal metrics with scale factors $h_i dx^i$ is the inverse $\frac{1}{h_i} \partial_{x_i}$
one finally arrives at

$$\triangle f = \frac{1}{\prod_i h_i} \partial_{\theta_k}\  \frac{\prod_i h_i}{h_k^2} \partial_{\theta_k} $$

By a product ansatz

$$f= R(r) \prod_k \Theta_k\left(\theta_k\right)$$

the Laplace equation

$$\frac{\triangle f}{f} = \sum_k c_k(r,\theta_1,\dots,\theta_{k-1})\text(ODE)(\theta_k) = 0$$

can be solved backwards for a set of ordinary linear second order ODE's with a tree of quantum numbers by solving for square integrable solutions on the intervals for all angles.

Comment: Well, i can follow your reasoning line. But honestly, i don't think we are talking about the same thing